# Powershell select line number line only from file

Tags: powershell

I like to go through a log file and list the line number and line only
my current script is

```
#$ERROR_MESSAGE = Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String "ORA-" | select LineNumber,Line
```

I needed to be like this:

> line 592:    RMAN-00571: ==================================================
>
> line 593:  RMAN-00569: ========== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ==========
>
> line 594:  RMAN-00571: ==================================================
>
> line 595:  RMAN-03002: failure of backup plus archivelog command at 09/05/2015 00:20:41
>
> line 596:  ORA-19502: write error on file "vsqgb979_1_1", block number 27408097 (block size=8192)
>
> line 597:  ORA-27030: skgfwrt: sbtwrite2 returned error
>
> line 598:  ORA-19511: Error received from media manager layer, error text:

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Select-String -Pattern "ORA-" -Path $_.FullName -SimpleMatch | %{ "{0}: {1}" -f ($_.LineNumber, $_.Line)}
```

Comment: There was no need to use the Get-Content call, since you can tell Select-String what file look in, so I got rid of that. Then all I did was pipe it into a for-each ("%") loop, and create a formatted string that contained the line number and the line, which is the last part of the pipe.

Comment: Thanks allot ... this is huge for me, I need to do allot of reading and testing ...

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but something like this should work:

```
$ERROR_MESSAGE = Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String "ORA-" | select @{e={'Line {0}: {1}' -f $_.LineNumber, $_.Line}; n='LineInfo'}
```

Comment: I get this ... how to ignore "@{LineInfo=" and "}"
         @{LineInfo=Line 276: ORA-31693: Table data object "OCS_SUPERVISOR"."OCS_IMPORT_LOG" failed to load/unload and i
s being skipped due to error:} @{LineInfo=Line 277: ORA-02354: error in exporting/importing data} @{LineInfo=Line 278: O
RA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 8 with name "_SYSSMU8_3132418526$" too small} @{LineInfo=Line 381: O
RA-39181: Only partial table data may be exported due to fine grain access control on "OCS_SUPERVISOR"."DEOSchedule234_T
AB"}

Comment: Do the filtering with a Where-Object block before the select.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i'm sorry, but sure I did google it before I ask him .. and I could not understand it nor understand the connection!

Comment: Your comment is really too difficult to understand what it is that you actually want to come out. Please edit the question to add the new information in a format that can be understood.

Comment: His issue is how he is exporting that data. Perhaps just add a `| Select-Object -Expand LineInfo`

Comment: @EBGreen on the output i get @{LineInfo= which I do not want to have

Comment: Aah...in that case, -expand should fix it as per Matt's suggestion.

Comment: @Data-Base For what its worth this solution did work but how you were exporting the data was an issue you did not share. What you were seeing is how PowerShell converts objects to strings. Using `-Expand` just created a string array.

Comment: It was A script that checks errors in oracle RMAN logs, I have a working .Net app that I made, I was checking if I can migrate it to Powershell